# calling python code inside rshiny for building simple interface

Tags: python, r, shiny

I have a certain python code(shared below) to display the similar descriptions as entered by the user(validation data) to the historical information. Now due to some reason, I want to use Rshiny to create a simple interface, which would take two fields such as:

```
Enter the description:

Enter the region:

And gives me the similar text
```

Code used is:

```
new_description='EDAP Scenario is'

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

description_list=train_data['description'].unique().tolist()
##train_data has historical descriptions
similar_description=[]
for description in description_list:
    result=similar(new_description, description)
    if result >=0.8:
        similar_CR.append(cr)
```

Here the new_description which I have entered explicitly needs to be taken from the interface.

I am very novice in R/Rshiny. Any help/starting point would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a skeleton for your app.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  textInput("description", label = "Enter the Description:"),
  textInput("region", label = "Enter the Region:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("txtoutput")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$txtoutput <- renderPrint({
    print(paste("description: ", input$description, "and region: ", input$region))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I dont know exactly how you want to combine R/shiny with python and where/how the input from "description" and "region" are used in the python code.
Anyway, you might want to look at this package - **rPython**.
Or you further explain, what exactly you are trying to achieve.